24.04 LTS Installing linux kernel 6.8.0.45-generic failed
I found a similar problem, with a different solution, so I thought to make my own post. When running sudo apt upgrade I'm having an error installing the latest linux kernel 6.8.0.45.45
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic is already the newest version (6.8.0-45.45).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area....(bad exit status: 2)
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.8.0-45-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 5.2.14 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-44-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.8.0-44-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 5.2.14 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-44-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.8.0-45.45); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...(bad exit status: 2)
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.8.0-45-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 5.2.14 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 failed for evdi(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log shows the following
DKMS make.log for evdi-5.2.14 for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Mon Sep 23 08:12:17 AM PDT 2024
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build SRCROOT=/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic'
make --no-print-directory -C /usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic/Makefile modules
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=arch/x86/entry/syscalls all
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
set -e; mkdir -p include/config/; trap "rm -f include/config/.tmp_kernel.release" EXIT; { echo 6.8.0-45-generic; } > include/config/.tmp_kernel.release; if [ ! -r include/config/kernel.>
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.asm-generic obj=arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm \
generic=include/uapi/asm-generic
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/uapi/linux/; trap "rm -f include/generated/uapi/linux/.tmp_version.h" EXIT; {        if [ 12 -gt 255 ]; then echo \#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 395519; >
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/; trap "rm -f include/generated/.tmp_utsrelease.h" EXIT; {   if [ `echo -n "6.8.0-45-generic" | wc -c ` -gt 64 ]; then echo '"6.8.0-45-generic" exceed>
set -e; mkdir -p include/generated/; trap "rm -f include/generated/.tmp_compile.h" EXIT; { ./scripts/mkcompile_h "x86_64" "gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0" "ld"; } > include/gen>
./scripts/remove-stale-files
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:249: archheaders] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:22: all] Error 2

Running dkms status returns the following
evdi/1.14.1: added
evdi/1.14.2+dfsg, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/1.14.2+dfsg, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
evdi/5.2.14: added

Is this an issue with dkms? Something else I'm missing?

Thanks to @Leejjon I was able to get on the right track and get the latest kernel updated succesfully. The issue appears to be compatiability with evdi-dkms, which is used for multiple displays with USB 3.0, which is required by a Dell dock I use.
I first ran sudo apt remove dkms evdi-dkms to remove those packages and was then able to run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade successfully. I then was able to reinstall evdi-dkms with sudo apt install evdi-dkms and reboot successfully to the latest kernel. We'll see what happens when the next kernel update comes out and if I have to do those steps again.
EDITED TO UPDATE: I did have to remove dkms and evdi-dkms in order to update the kernel again the next time.

I had the exact same error on both 6.8.0.44 and 6.8.0.45 migrating from 6.8.0.41. I could not even boot my machine (my machine was stuck with a dell logo, running the kernel in recovery mode showed a kernel panic), I had to switch to the old 6.8.0.41 kernel via the grub boot loader.
When I ran sudo apt update I got the exact same error you have.
I did first tried to uninstall display link but that didn't solve the problem (followed https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683699-how-to-uninstall-displaylink-ubuntu-software).
Then I found this thread:
https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67852
And the following command mentioned in it solved the error in your post:
sudo apt install evdi-dkms
Then the apt update succeeded and I could finally boot with the latest 6.8.0.45 kernel. I hope it works for you too.
Update: Fun fact, obviously I wanted to install the display link drivers again to get my docking station to work. And this actually removed the evdi-dkms package again. But fortunately my system kept working fine.
Update2: After installing the display link drivers again it does kind of break my Software updater:


Thank you, this lead me down the right path. I ran sudo apt remove dkms evdi-dkms to remove those packages and was then able to run sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt update successfully. I then was able to reinstall evdi-dkms with sudo apt install evdi-dkms and reboot succesfully to the latest kernel. We'll see what happens when the next kernel update comes out.
